# How do I make vega-lite order days starting with monday?

Tags: vega-lite

I have this specification.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "description": "Some garbage test data",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "01 Jan 2012 23:00:00", "price": 150},
      {"date": "02 Jan 2012 00:00:00", "price": 100},
      {"date": "03 Jan 2012 01:00:00", "price": 170},
      {"date": "04 Jan 2012 02:00:00", "price": 165},
      {"date": "05 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 20},
      {"date": "06 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 300},
      {"date": "07 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 200},
      {"date": "08 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 300},
      {"date": "09 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 500}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "day"
    },
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "average"}
  },
  "config": {"axisY": {"minExtent": 30}}
}
```

This displays the daily averages in a pretty chart, however having it start with "Sunday" is very weird in countries where the week starts with Monday.

How do I change the order so it starts with Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sort` property to set the axis order:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "description": "Some garbage test data",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "01 Jan 2012 23:00:00", "price": 150},
      {"date": "02 Jan 2012 00:00:00", "price": 100},
      {"date": "03 Jan 2012 01:00:00", "price": 170},
      {"date": "04 Jan 2012 02:00:00", "price": 165},
      {"date": "05 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 20},
      {"date": "06 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 300},
      {"date": "07 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 200},
      {"date": "08 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 300},
      {"date": "09 Jan 2012 03:00:00", "price": 500}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "day",
      "sort": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    },
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "average"}
  },
  "config": {"axisY": {"minExtent": 30}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I apply this for `timeUnit: dayhours`?